# NSJSONSerialization extra argument error in call conversion to Swift 2.1

Tags: swift, error-handling, swift2

New to Swift and converting code from swift 1.2 to swift 2.1, extra error handler comes up and I don't know where to add the new do, try, catch.

code is below and attached in screenshot.

---

```
   var error: NSError?

                let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                if (error != nil) {
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
                }
                else {
                    let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

                    if status == "OK" {
                        self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
                        self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

                        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

                        let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
                        self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                        self.originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
                        self.destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

                        self.calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration()

                        completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
                    }
                    else {
                        completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            completionHandler(status: "Destination is nil.", success: false)
        }
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: "Origin is nil", success: false)
    }
}
```

[screenshot of MapTasks.swift file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d73FB.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` method call `throws` an error. So, you will have to `try` that method call and catch it in a `do { //... } catch { //... }` block.

Refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) link for more details on Error handling in Swift.

```
do {
    let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(directionsData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

    let status = dictionary["status"] as! String

    if status == "OK" {
        self.selectedRoute = (dictionary["routes"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>)[0]
        self.overviewPolyline = self.selectedRoute["overview_polyline"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

        let legs = self.selectedRoute["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>

        let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
        self.originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

        let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
        self.destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

        self.originAddress = legs[0]["start_address"] as! String
        self.destinationAddress = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_address"] as! String

        self.calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration()

        completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
    }

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error ==> \(error)")
    completionHandler(status: "", success: false)
}
```

Comment: fixed first error but two other popped up 
1.
self.calculateDistanceAndDuration()  

shows error: value of type 'MapTasks' has no member 'calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration' now though.

2.
use of unresolved identifer 'directionsData
'let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(**directionsData**!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>'

Comment: Ensure you have the function `calculateTotalDistanceAndDuration` and `directionsData` object are available in your class